# Change format date from japanese date format into common date format in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

how do i change the format if the date 2018年06月08日 = 2018-06-08

```
var getStart = $("input[name='start_date_period']").val();
var getEnd = $("input[name='end_date_period']").val();
var startDate = new Date( getStart ) ;
var endDate = new Date( getEnd );

var str = startDate.toString("yyyy-MM-DD");
```

i tried like that but it didnt work

Comment: but that is php format isn't it?

Comment: What is PHP format?

Comment: ah sorry. it works but the result "2018-06-08-".. how do i remove the last "-"?

Comment: the result just "2018"

Comment: If it's a date typed by the end user you can't trust any simple string manipulation. You'll have to find a full proper date handling library with i18n support. Anything else will just fail randomly, probably when you're about the leave for the weekend :)

Comment: `"2018年06月08日".match(/\d+/g).join('-')`. I really shouldn't do this while busy doing other things…

Comment: "Common date" is a bit biased, tbh.